# Capture everything inside a rect in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a rect, which has inside of it a portion of my UI, I want to take a 'screenshot' of everything inside of that rect and put it into a .jpeg file.

I have absolutely no idea how I can do this, and if it's even possible. Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is use a **[RenderTexture](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderTexture.html)**

- Create a RenderTexture Unity Object in the editor
- Create a Camera that sees exactly what you want in your screenshot.
  Cameras in Unity have an option called **Target Texture**. Put your RenderTexture in this field. The result is that the camera will render in this texture instead of on the screen. See the [Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RenderTexture.html) for detailed examples.
- Make a script that has access to your RenderTexture Object. This script create a Texture2D using [Texture2D.ReadPixels](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.ReadPixels.html). This allows to create a Texture2D object from the texture.
- Use [Texture2D.EncodeToJpg](https://docs.unity3d.com/550/Documentation/ScriptReference/Texture2D.EncodeToJPG.html) to save your Texture2D in a file

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TakeScreenshotAndSave : MonoBehaviour
{
//Object To Screenshot
[SerializeField] private RectTransform _objToScreenshot;

//Assign the button to take screenshot on clicking
[SerializeField] private Button _takeScreenshotButton;

void Start()
{
    
_takeScreenshotButton.onClick.AddListener(OnClickTakeScreenshotAndSaveButton);
}

private void OnClickTakeScreenshotAndSaveButton()
{
    StartCoroutine(TakeSnapShotAndSave());
}

//Using a Coroutine instead of normal method
public IEnumerator TakeSnapShotAndSave()
{
    //Code will throw error at runtime if this is removed
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    //Get the corners of RectTransform rect and store it in a array vector
    Vector3[] corners = new Vector3[4];
    _objToScreenshot.GetWorldCorners(corners);

    //Remove 100 and you will get error
    int width = ((int)corners[3].x - (int)corners[0].x) - 100;
    int height = (int)corners[1].y - (int)corners[0].y;
    var startX = corners[0].x;
    var startY = corners[0].y;

    //Make a temporary texture and read pixels from it
    Texture2D ss = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    ss.ReadPixels(new Rect(startX, startY, width, height), 0, 0);
    ss.Apply();

    Debug.Log("Start X : " + startX + " Start Y : " + startY);
    Debug.Log("Screen Width : " + Screen.width + " Screen Height : " + 
    Screen.height);
    Debug.Log("Texture Width : " + width + " Texture Height : " + height);

    //Save the screenshot to disk
    byte[] byteArray = ss.EncodeToPNG();
    string savePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/ScreenshotSave.png";
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(savePath, byteArray);
    Debug.Log("Screenshot Path : " + savePath);

    // Destroy texture to avoid memory leaks
    Destroy(ss);
}
}
```